# Proxy b/w client and services using webClient and Mono

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am writing a proxy b/w client and services, in proxy I just do need to some basic validation and pass on the request to services, I have written below code for the same. Could you please let me know that is this right way or is there any other better ways to handle this.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> handlePostRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        return webClient.post().uri("/some/uri").headers(headers -> request.headers())
                        .body(request.bodyToMono(DataBuffer.class), DataBuffer.class)
                        .exchange()
                            .flatMap(response -> ServerResponse.status(response.statusCode())
                                            .headers(c -> response.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((name, value) -> c.put(name, value)))
                                            .body(response.bodyToMono(DataBuffer.class), DataBuffer.class));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any validation in this code snippet (despite the fact that you're mentioning that requirement in your questions).

I don't see any error management either, which should handle what the server should respond in case the remote server returns an HTTP error (should it just forward the response?), or if it doesn't answer and a timeout occurs.

Other than that, and given the short requirements you've shared, this could be right for your use case.

Please note that, depending on your choice of HTTP client library and server, `DataBuffer` instances can be `PooledDataBuffer` - which means references are counted on those to allow them to be reused and code using those is responsible for releasing them. In this case, you are reusing those buffers to forward them to the client as request body or to the server as response body. The `release` operation will be done for you before they're written to the network.

Finally, if you're looking for more complex features, you can take a look at the [Spring Cloud Gateway project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway) which does that and much more.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the info. In my case I don't need to validate the request, only the headers I have to validate (these are I am validating in Filters), and do not want to read the request body and just pass that as it is. So PooledDataBuffer would be good choice for that ?

Comment: The type of buffer is chosen by the webflux server/client. You have to assume they’re pooled and release them when needed. You don’t need to explicitly choose their type.